# On a single section of multiple items in mobile device, whether to scroll horizontally or vertically?

Tags: mobile, touch-screen, scrolling, microinteractions

I am designing some file sending app similar to email apps. Below is an example of layout.

For the [files attached] section, which scrolling method is more preferable, horizontal scroll, or vertical? Seems horizontal scroll allows the information above to be fixed, but some articles says horizontal scroll is less efficient and less natural to users. So I'd like to ask for more evidence or experiences about this scrolling problem. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I like the horizontal scrolling idea. Every app should not be design in the same way. What works for them might not work for you. Whether to use horizontal scrolling or not depends largely on your content and design.

For your case, horizontal scrolling might be more effective than vertical scrolling. You already said it, user can scroll and see the files attached and make any necessary changes to the message box easily. The design challenge in horizontal scrolling is to make it noticeable to the user. The user must know (or at least made aware) that they can view more files by scrolling the content horizontally.

There are some news app that uses horizontal scrolling to view their news content. [Facebook paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Paper#/media/File:Paper_by_Facebook_(sample).PNG) also uses horizontal scrolling if it helps you to know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I too feel the horizontal scrolling seems less natural in this case, for whatever design you have mentioned its good to go with vertical design.